# Pytorch 0.4: Should the requires_grad flag of the network input be set to True during training?

Tags: pytorch

The `requires_grad` flag of input is default `False` during my last training. I was wondering if I should set it to `True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So generally:

- For all **tensors / weights that you want to be trained** the `requires_grad` flag has to be **`True`**. 
  This would be the case for your **parameters** resp. **weights** and **biases**. So there you want the flag to be **`True`**. But this is already default value for predefined modules like `nn.Linear`, `nn.Embedding`. `nn.Conv2d` etc. So you don't have to change it.
- For things like **inputs** the `requires_grad` flag needs to be **`False`** since you don't want to train your input data.

I hope this answers your question, if you want to know something more specific just ask!